# Is carbonated water more conductive than salt water or baking soda-water mix?

Tags: electricity, conductors

Sorry for this entry level question, I'm an amateur, and I was wondering about alternative water mixtures for electrolysis.

My question is: Does carbonated water have better conductivity for electrolysis compared to salt water or sodium bicarbonate-water mixture?

And yes, I am aware of the danger of using salt water for electrolysis, but it's just for an example.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It all depends upon concentration, but given solutions with equal molar concentrations, salt and sodium bicarbonate will ionize much more than carbonic acid (formed from carbon dioxide and water). The higher ion concentration will result in higher conductivity for the salt and sodium carbonate solutions. The size of ions has some effect on diffusion/conduction rates, but the low ionization of carbonic acid will be the dominant factor in this case.